# How to synchronize time-shifted in R?

Tags: r, time-series, synchronization

I have some data from meteorological observatory, but it contains some problem. Due to the fact that the sensors do not always work stably, there was some shift in time. Here's what it roughly looks like:

```
       `REF DATE-TIME`         `DATE-TIME` CO2_dry CH4_dry   H2O
1 2020-09-27 00:00:00 2020-09-27 00:00:00     416.    2.1   1.64
2 2020-09-27 00:00:05 2020-09-27 00:00:05     416.    2.10  1.64
3 2020-09-27 00:00:09 2020-09-27 00:00:10     416.    2.10  1.63
4 2020-09-27 00:00:14 2020-09-27 00:00:15     416.    2.10  1.64
5 2020-09-27 00:00:19 2020-09-27 00:00:21     417.    2.10  1.64
6 2020-09-27 00:00:24 2020-09-27 00:00:23     416.    2.10  1.63
*** (switched off for 6 minutes)
7 2020-09-27 00:00:25 2020-09-27 00:06:26     416.    2.10. 1.63
```

In a few words: when the device was turned on after a malfunction, it began to count the time taking into account how much it had not worked. But I have a reference date-time column and this two columns are shifted, so I nave to synchronize them. A spread in values ​​​​of 3-6 milliseconds can be considered normal.
How I can synchronize the data? It is so important for research, but I have no clue how to make it :(

Comment: How do you know if it was switched off for 6 mins and not for 8? Do you have the reference date-time within your data?

Comment: 6 minutes was just an example. I know the the time when it was switched off, because the first column in data frame represents reference date-time.
And I found a mistake in text, now it fixed

Comment: Then I would compare `DATE-TIME` with `REF DATE-TIME` and if the difference is say bigger than 5 sec, I would substitute `DATE-TIME` with `REF DATE-TIME`.